# @dynamic implementation where to find it?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, core-data, ios4

If I have a property that is declared as @dynamic where do I normally implement the setter and getter? I need to locate where this is defined in a code base I was given.

How is this tied to MSManangedObject?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about a subclass of NSManagedObject here, the setters/getters are provided by CoreData.

Comment: are the subclasses generated automatically by the model mapping ? or we create that manually?

Comment: Typically you create an entity first and then when you create a model class in Xcode you point it to the entity you created and a subclass of NSManagedObject is generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two different things:

- If you are talking about @dynamic as used in classes generated by the data modeler to represent core data entities, then the implementations are generated by core data as well. You just cannot access them. I think you can override and put your own in but I have not investigated that. So generally speaking don't worry about them.
- @dynamic as used in classes you define (not core data) means that your are going to type in the getter and setter for the property. There are plenty of examples in the documentation on what these should look like. Generally you would only do this if you are not going to store the value for the property in a variable, are going to somehow transform it first, or need to hook some other processing into the getter/setter concept.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "typing in" the getter/setter. But a custom getter/setter like you are describing does not mean they are @dynamic. @dynamic means you are providing no getter/setter at all at compile time, but you promise to introduce them (or handle a forward) later at runtime.  For a normal custom getter/setter (calculated, transformed, whatever) you specify neither @synthesize nor @dynamic.

Comment: Yep, you don't need to do a @syntheize or @dynamic declaration. I also just checked the objective C doco and it says "...either by providing method implementations directly or at runtime..." which means that you code them (typing in) or some other mechanism generates them (core data for example). I've always put in the @dynamic declaration if I'm putting in the implementation. No reason other than being clear about it. :-)